SAP BO WEBI link two queries
I am relatively new to SAP BO and need support with the following requirement:
I have 2 queries:
The first query contains data with participant names for events. An event has many participants.
The exact structure is:

Event_ID
Participant_fullname

The second query contains the names of the speakers at the events. An event has one or more speakers.
Here is the structure of the second query:

Event_ID
Trainer_Firstname
Trainer_lastname

My goal is to combine these two queries and get a list with the following data:

Event_ID
Participant_fullname
Trainer_1 (fistname + " " + lastname)
Trainer_2 (fistname + " " + lastname)

For this I linked the queries via the Event_ID column.
My approach was to get the name of the first speaker using the MIN() function. However, this fails. When I create a variable with the following formula: =MIN(Firstname + " " + Lastname) I get the error "#MultipleValue"
Can someone help me please?
Thanks and best regards
Iskasa
Sample Data:
Query 1:
Event_ID  Participant_fullname
1         Mr. A
1         Mr. B
1         Mr. C
1         Mr. D
2         Mrs. E
2         Mrs. F
2         Mrs. G

Query 2:
Event_ID  Firstname  Lastname
1         John       Monday
1         Jim        Friday
2         Tim        West
2         Tom        South
2         Ed         East

